# how to remove &amp;quot; in json string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring

i am struck one module for more than one week, i have a login page it contains username and password and i need to pass my values to web service to check for login. my web service contain only one parameter name called "Param" i need to pass the values to "Param". However there is no issue while calling web service when i enter valid username and password jam getting failed this happens only because of this **&quot** additional text added while i pass my values to login page

here my output printed in Nslog :

```
{&amp;quot;login_values&amp;quot;:{&amp;quot;\&amp;quot;password&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;xxxxx@1234&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;\&amp;quot;loginid&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;xxxxxxx@gmail.com&amp;quot;}}
```

my sample code :

```
    NSString *login = self.username.text;
    NSString *password = self.password.text;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:login forKey:@"loginid"];
    [dict setValue:password forKey:@"password"];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *resultAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", resultAsString);
    NSData *jsonData1 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *addnewuser_values = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *append = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"login_values\":"];
    NSString *slash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"}"];
    NSString *append1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",append,addnewuser_values,slash];
   NSString *modStr=[[append1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;quot;" withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"locginCheck_method:\n%@",append);
    request.param = modStr;
```

i need to remove that &quot;

Comment: ya i need to remove &amp;quot;

Comment: Your php backend obfuscates JSON, get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

Check if this would help u

Comment: can u explin in detail

Comment: NSString *finalString = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;quot" withString:@""];

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` api like this below:-

```
NSString *modStr=[[jsonStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;quot;" withString:@""]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@" "];
```

Output:-

```
{login_values:{password:xxxxx@1234 loginid:xxxxxxx@gmail.com}}
```

Comment: i need my output like this: {login_values:{password:xxxxx@1234 loginidxxxxxxx@gmail.com}}

Comment: still same result jam getting

Comment: Can you paste your code exactly how you are trying??

Comment: Did you print NSLog(@"%@",append1)??

Comment: ya while printing append1 i getting my expected output in nslog but the same value jam passing to web services jam getting issue